# CSS not working if set in "%"

Tags: android, css, html, google-maps-api-3

I wish to make a  tag's height and width to 100%, now in other examples it worked using  tag demonstrated below. But in the code given below, if I remove the "style="width: 370px; height: 505px"" from the  and add the following code after meta tag

```
<style type="text/css>
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#map-canvas{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
```

it doesn't work.

---

```
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var shape;
      function initialize() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        shape = new google.maps.Polygon({
          strokeColor: '#ff0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#ff0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        shape.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPoint);

      }

      function addPoint(e) {

        var vertices = shape.getPath();
        vertices.push(e.latLng);

      }
      function clearmap(){      
        initialize();  
      }


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 370px; height: 505px"></div>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="clearmap"()>
  </body>
```

​

Comment: in the second line I forgot to mention "from <div> tag". Also, forgot to end the quotes after CSS. Sorry.

Comment: used to html,body{height:100%;}

Comment: It only shows the button, and the map doesn't show up.

Comment: ohhhh, worked!!!, thank you Rohit Azad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle out of your code

http://jsfiddle.net/jRwDs/3/

...and the answer from Rohit Azad, to add the `html` tag to the document style, seems to fix your problem (at least on jsfiddle).